# Embedding Firebase social login in an iframe

Tags: firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth, google-signin, facebook-authentication

I have a React app embedded in an iframe. The app uses firebase-authentication to sign in using Google, Facebook or Twitter. While the authentication mechanism works perfectly outside an iframe, it does not work within an iframe due to cross-origin issues. Any ideas how to work around this?

Here's the code that embeds the React app in an iframe:

```
<iframe
    id="myframe"
    src="https://example.com/my-frame"
    scrolling="no"
></iframe>
```

When the React app redirects to the social login, I get the following error message in Chrome DevTools:

> Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xyz&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+profile+openid&redirect_uri=https://example.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler&state=AH..oE' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

It appears that Google Sign In is sending `x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN` header which is preventing the browser from opening that page. Is there a way to work around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth providers like accounts.google.com refuse to render in a frame or iframe. This is done for security reasons.

There is nothing you can do to bypass that. However, you could switch to using `signInWithPopup` instead if you are using Firebase Auth to sign-in from an iframe.

Comment: Thanks @bojeil. The `signInWithPopup` idea was fantastic.